# Using CSS float for a masonry-like layout

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have three divs of equal width acting as three columns. There's a fourth div that I want to position in the right column directly beneath the div already in that column.

*I've linked the way I want it to look in the comments. [I was constrained to using no more than two links in this question post.]*

I want to do this elegantly making full use of the doc flow and styling of float, clear, display, and/or position . I don't want want to hack away with margins, padding, tops, rights, lefts etc. if possible. I'm not interested in any javascript.

The order of the first two divs are important and must be maintained. In fact, there are only two permutations of the doc order and both are shown below.

These two fiddles are as close as I've come: [One](http://jsfiddle.net/93nymkho/1/) and [Two](http://jsfiddle.net/o00myogu/1/). Note that classes are semantic wrt position.

They share the exact same CSS, but differ in their HTML.

**One - HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-right">top-right</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">bottom-right</div>
</div>
```

**Two - HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-right">top-right</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">bottom-right</div>    
  <div class="left">left</div>
</div>
```

NOTES: The only difference is the order of the last two divs.

**Both - CSS**

```
.container{
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
},

div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
}

.left{
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

.top-right{
    background-color: green;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
}

.bottom-right{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}

.center{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The question: How do I get rid of that white-space?

Comment: It should look like [this](http://imgur.com/1P3B9K6)

[Sorry to post this as a comment - I was constrained to using no more than two links in the question]

Comment: `Float` is unlikely to **ever** give you a Masonry-type layout unless you add extra wrappers & so forth...that's why Masonry exists. Flexbox would probably help but, IMO, its support isn't quite there for full production...depending on your target browsers.

Comment: you can do a small hack if the elements are static and it remains the same. here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/93nymkho/3/

Comment: **@sanjithedward** Should of mentioned that it needs be dynamic. I'm using the normal flow to order the divs in a mobile view.  **@Paulie_D** I suspected I was aiming too elegant. Thanks for confirming my suspicion.  I ended up adding another div identical to `.top-right` above `.bottom-right` in the **One - HTML** ordering (thank you React components).  I set their displays to be 'none' and 'block' on desktop and vice versa when in mobile view.